# $f_j(x) = sin(jx)$ has no subsequence that converges at any x

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that the sequence of functions $f_j(x) = sin(jx)$ has no subsequence that converges at every $x$?

I know that a Cauchy sequence that has a convergence subsequence converges, but $f_j(x)$ doesn't seem to be Cauchy, so I can't use this.

Comment: What level is this question?  Can we assume Lebesgue measure?  If $f_{j_k}(x)$ converges for all $x \in [0,2\pi]$, then by dominated convergence, $f_{j_k}$ would be Cauchy in the $L^1[0,2\pi]$ norm.  So compute the $L_1$ norm of differences to see that fails.

Comment: I haven't learned about (Lebesgue) measure theory, unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, if this is a problem given in a book, look at the material immediately before it for a clue of what method to use.

Comment: The section is about uniform convergence, exchange of limit and differentiation, exchange of limit and integration, Weierstrass M-test. But no other hints. The $f_j$s do not converge.